# Select 1 row not selected within last 5 minutes

Tags: mysql

From a table with cols id and timestamp, how can I select:
any 1 row as long as it has not been selected within the last 5 mins
?
TIA

Comment: You mean the `timestamp` older than 5 mins exactly?

Comment: Do you have a way of amending a timestamp when a row is selected? ( mysql doesn't)

Comment: Set a is_selected-flag when selected...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how we define a row as `selected`. We need to keep track of whether a row has been selected already, probably by adding another column (with a flag) and your query will look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) <= 5
AND selected = 0;
```

Comment: Where and how  would you set selected after this query is run?

Comment: @P.Salmon the application needs to keep track of the rows and update `selected` flag.

Comment: @DarshanMehta But then I would need to un-set the selected records after 5 mins somehow, wouldn't I? (This is a kind of revision quiz for students so the table would contain only a few hundred records.)

Comment: The query won't pick up any records that are older than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `selected` flag, a timestamp should be enough.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, lastTimeSelectedTimestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) > 5
```

Which means, SELECT all entries FROM table FOR WHICH the lastTimeSelectedTimestamp lies more than 5 minutes in the past.